# Fast full-text search on XML files located on file system. What strategy to choose?

Tags: java, xml, search, indexing

I need to implement the fastest possible full-text search on XML files located on file system. Basically I need to determine if some of XML node values contains specific keywords.
I've considered a few options:

- iterate through files in directory -> read file line by line -> use Matcher / Pattern to determine if keyword is here
- iterate through files in directory -> use SAX parser
- create index on required XML nodes as soon as new file arrives to directory (for example, using Solr) and then query index engine

What strategy better to choose and why?

Answer (score 0):

If xml files are small in size (few KBs/few MBs), then I suggest that you should read them line by line (or use some other xml parsing technique to read them). Solr will prove useful when you have a very big xml file. Solr can read small files also easily (However, it all depends on how much time you have)

Not sure about SAX parser.

Comment: Files are small, but there are a lot of them (hundreds of thousands) and new files are arriving heavily.

Comment: I guess solr might be appropriate in that case (not sure above SAX parser). I assume that you will maintain historical data also ? Do remember though that it will take time for solr to index all the documents depending on your schema and the number of documents you are committing.

or you can also look at powershell to do a quick search on the documents (not sure about the performance).

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/13/use-powershell-to-simplify-access-to-xml-data.aspx